# if-then batch to map drives

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to get a couple scripts to work with each other, but I am not entirely familiar with the if-then commands, I am using wizapp and I have my info ready to go, but I don't know how to map a specific location based on the output of wizapp, as a for instance 
if %siteid%=="0"

How do I map that to a drive, I have 10 different drives that have to be mapped using that
info, and I am lost, siteid will obviously be different in each if then statement?

Answer (score 0):

This is relatively easy to do. I will provide manual instructions as it is extremely useful to learn and will improve your coding skills.

```
C:\windows\system32> net view

Server Name                Remark
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\\PC1
\\PC2
\\PC3
\\PC4
\\PC5
\\PC6
\\PC7
\\PC8
\\PC9
\\SERVER
The command completed successfully.


C:\windows\system32> net view \\PC1

Shared resources at \\PC1


Share name  Type  Used as  Comment

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SharedDocs  Disk
The command completed successfully.


C:\windows\system32> net use ( Drive letter A-Z ) \\PC1\SharedDocs

The command completed successfully.
```

---

Now open up My Computer and youll see that PC1 is registered as a drive onto your computer.